# How do I change an attribute or class using only Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to change the styling attribute values of all elements that have the class "post-feature" and contain an attribute value of "http"

So the div element will look like the following:

`<div class="post-feature" style="backgroundimage:url(http://local.test.com/test_image.jpg);">`

So far the http check works. But I am not able to set the attribute value.

I have the following code

```
var features = document.getElementsByClassName(".post-feature")
[0].getAttribute("style");

if (features.includes("http")) {
features.setAttribute("background-color", "orange");

} else {

  alert('no change');

}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. What attribute must contain a value of `http`?

Comment: @ Scott Marcus The background image attribute must contain http

Comment: Ok, but background image is not an "attribute", it's a CSS property.

Comment: drop the `.` from `document.getElementsByClassName(".post-feature")` for a start, because the lass name you are looking for doesn't start with a `.`

Comment: I updated my answer and added a second sample. Please review and comment, and it would also be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll('.post-feature[style*="http"]')` to find those elements.

Then simply iterate through them and i.e. set their background color with
 `element.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';`

Now, if you want to make sure you only target elements having a `background-image` and `http`, you can use this selector:
 `querySelectorAll('.post-feature[style*="http"][style*="background-image"]')`

Also, by adding an `i` (or `I`) just before the end bracket `[style*="http"i]`, the value will be compared case-insensitively.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.post-feature[style*="http"]');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  
      elements[i].style.backgroundColor = 'orange';   /* add propert value */
      
      /*  replace class
      elements[i].className = 'myClass';
      */
      
      /*  add a class
      elements[i].classList.add('myClass');
      */
  }
  /* temp log */
  console.log('Found ', elements.length,' element(s)');
})
```

```css
div {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
}
div + div {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-feature" style="background-image:url(http://local.test.com/test_image.jpg);"></div>

<div class="post-feature"></div>

<div class="post-feature" style="background-image:url(http://local.test.com/test_image.jpg);"></div>

<div class="post-feature"></div>
```

---

*Updated*

To only change styling, like colors etc., you don't even need a script, you can use CSS alone

```css
div {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
}
div + div {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
/*  for elements that contain "http" and "background-image"  */
.post-feature[style*="http"i][style*="background-image"i] {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-feature" style="background-image:url(http://local.test.com/test_image.jpg);"></div>

<div class="post-feature"></div>

<div class="post-feature" style="background-image:url(HTTP://local.test.com/test_image.jpg);"></div>

<div class="post-feature"></div>
```

*As a note, and as discussed in a few comments, if to make sure it is the `background-image` property that also contain the `http` in its `url()`, you can adjust the selector to this, which as well can be used without any script, as a CSS rule*

```
.post-feature[style*="background-image:url(http"i] {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

*The above selector can of course also be used in the first sample, like this*

```
querySelectorAll('.post-feature[style*="background-image:url(http"i]')
```

Comment: Suppose the elements look like this: `<div class="post-feature" style="border-image: url("http:///images/border.png") 30 30 repeat;backgroundimage:url(test_image.jpg);"></div>`. Your code will falsely pick up that div as one that should have an orange background.

Comment: @ScottMarcus One can create a scenario where almost anything is breakable. My answer shows how to use `querySelectorAll`, where it is possible to simpy add more selectors to avoid such falsey pick up

Comment: @ScottMarcus I also tested my solution with the markup in your answer, and it works perfect

Comment: First, your code does *not* work perfectly with my example code (above, in these comments). It incorrectly turns that div orange. Second, your solution has a very large vulnerability in it, hardly out of the ordinary code that one might expect.

Comment: First, to catch background and http, do `querySelectorAll('.post-feature[style*="http"][style*="background-image"]')` ...second, here is my code with your markup https://jsfiddle.net/ct8ko86f/ ... so I really don't understand what your are talking about

Comment: Your example uses the markup from my answer below. It doesn't use the example code I gave in the comment **above**. I have adjusted my answer's markup to include that now to show that my solution works with this markup, but your posted answer does not work with that code.

Comment: See this: https://jsfiddle.net/qj1tp8s0/3/ as it shows your posted answer with my suggested markup. You will see that it incorrectly picks up the last `div`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus And I said, it is easy to solve that with an updated selector https://jsfiddle.net/ct8ko86f/1/

Comment: And, as I originally commented. The answer (as you posted it above) will break when the markup varies. Just as you wrote that one can create a scenario where almost anything breaks, I would respond by saying that one should post answers that protect against that. If you have a solution, you should update your answer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I updated ... also, the OP only asks for the class and http, which my original answer covers

Comment: @ScottMarcus Why not focus on why yours is good, instead of telling that all the other answers is not?

Comment: My answer explains why mine is good. Also, your updated code does **not** work. You have a typo in the last `div` in your fiddle, you have `backgroundimage` not `background-image` and that's why the last `div` doesn't get erroneously picked up. If you correct that (https://jsfiddle.net/ru8kkmut/1/) you will see that your updated answer still doesn't work.

Comment: All that extra attribute selector does is checks the `style` property to see if it contains `http` and also `background-image`, but it doesn't test to see if the `background-image` property contains `http`.

Comment: To be fair, that typo originated in my first comment (above), but your solution doesn't work nonetheless.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Well, that typo comes from your code, in your first comment, still, I rest my case, as it obviously does not matter what I say.

Comment: I think you are taking this personally, when it's not. Answers should strive to be the best they can be. Your's has an obvious bug and that's all I'm trying to say. I haven't down voted you or in any way tried to insult you. I'm just explaining that your solution has a problem.

Comment: From: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, *Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.*

Comment: @ScottMarcus My solution does not cover all possible aspects, it show a technique one can use, and can very well cover much more than I showed, if one understand how to use it

Comment: I think that if "one understands how to use it" doesn't really apply since we're on stack overflow and the OP posted this question because, clearly, he doesn't know how to use it. That's the reason that answers should be as complete as possible or at least point out deficiencies.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use **[`querySelctorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** with a CSS query that selects the elements with the class you desire and, in most cases, you should use this instead of **[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** as that returns a "live node list" that causes the DOM to be re-scanned every time you access it.

Next, `setAttribute()` is for setting HTML element attributes. You are asking to change the value of a CSS property. While that *could* be accomplished with `setAttribute('style', value)`, it is very "old-school" and not the best approach, nor is `getAttribute('style')` the best way to read a CSS property value (it won't work if the CSS was set from a style sheet).

Also, your code is trying to access: `backgroundimage`, but the property is accessed as `background-image` when working in CSS and `backgroundImage` when accessing it via JavaScript.

To access the inline styles applied to an HTML element, just access the `style` property of that element, followed by the name of the CSS property you are interested in. For example:

```
var bColor = element.style.backgroundColor;
```

If the style has been applied to the element from an internal style sheet or an external style sheet, the above approach won't work for you and you'll need to get it another way, via [**`window.getComputedStyle()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

```
var bColor = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).backgroundColor;
```

But, note that `getComputedStyle()` doesn't always return the same value that you set - - it's the value after the browser has computed all factors. In this case, even paths that you wrote as relative references (without the "http") will be returned as absolute paths (with the http).

So, here is a modern approach that correctly checks only the `background-image` CSS property for the presence of `http`.

**NOTE**: This solution tests for `http` specifically in the `background-image` property. Unlike most of the other answers given, this code will correctly ignore `http` in other CSS properties besides `background-image`. Examine the CSS of the last `div` to see this in action.

```js
// querySelectorAll() is more efficient than getElementsByClassName()
var features = document.querySelectorAll(".post-feature");

// Loop over the list
for(var i = 0; i < features.length; i++){

  // Get access to the background-image property (called backgroundImage from JavaScript) value,
  // convert that value to lower case and check to see if "http" is in that value
  if(features[i].style.backgroundImage.toLowerCase().indexOf("http") > -1){
  
    // Set the CSS background-color property (called "backgroundColor" in JavaScript) to orange:
    features[i].style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    
    // Just for testing:
    features[i].textContent = features[i].style.backgroundImage;
    
  } else {
  
    alert("No change");
    
  }  
}
```

```css
.post-feature { width:100%; height:50px; border:1px solid black; background-color:gray; color:yellow; }
```

```html
<!-- The correct CSS property is "background-image", not "backgroundimage" -->
<div class="post-feature" style="background-image:url(http://local.test.com/test_image.jpg);"></div>
<div class="post-feature" style="background-image:url(test_image.jpg);"></div>
<div class="post-feature" style="background-image:url(http://local.test.com/test_image.jpg);"></div>
<div class="post-feature" 
     style="border-image: url('http:///images/border.png') 30 30 repeat;background-image:url(test_image.jpg);">I have "http" in one of my CSS properties, but not "background-image", so I shouldn't be orange.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.style.backgroundColor` and `indexOf`

```
var features = document.getElementsByClassName(".post-feature")[0].getAttribute("style");

if (features.indexOf("http") > -1) {

  features.style.backgroundColor = "orange";

} else {

  alert('no change');

}
```

Comment: This code will return a false positive if any CSS property in the element contains `http` in its value, not just `backgroundImage`.

Answer (score 0):

i think some wrong in your code, try this code

```
element.setAttribute("style", "background-color: orange;"); // bad
```

or

```
element.style.backgroundColor = "orange"; // good
```

Comment: Actually, the first bit of code is valid and will work (although the second bit is preferred).

Comment: two way is working perfect but I like the second because it's simple =)))

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/vywk72j8/2/

```
<div class="post-feature" style="background-image:url(http://local.test.com/test_image.jpg);">
tt</div>


var feature = document.getElementsByClassName("post-feature")[0];
if (feature.style.backgroundImage.indexOf("http") !== -1) {
    feature.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
} else {
    alert('no change');
}
```

In your code, you are fetching the attribute value in features

```
var features = document.getElementsByClassName(".post-feature")
[0].getAttribute("style");
```

Here features is a string containing attribute value, not an element so you cannot use it to set value.

Comment: This code will return a false positive if any CSS property in the element contains `http` in its value, not just `backgroundImage`.

Comment: my bad, I didnot go through the comments below the question. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Also, what if the HTML as the style written as: `url(HTTP://...)`?